# Deep nesting of project folder in a SBT multi-project project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an SBT project that aggregates over multiple projects like this:

```
object ClientCore extends Build {
/**
 * This is the root project
 */
lazy val rootProj = Project(id = "clientcore", base = file(".")) aggregate(
    utilsProj,
    commonUiProj,
    spatialMathProj,
    sessionManagerProj,
    lobbyProj,
)

/**
 * This is a utils library
 */
lazy val utilsProj = Project(id = "utils", base = file("Utils"))

/**
 * A shared library for UI elements
 */
lazy val commonUiProj = Project(id = "commonui", base = file("CommonUI"))

/**
 * This is a spatial math library
 */
lazy val spatialMathProj = Project(id = "spatialmath", base = file("SpatialMath"))

lazy val sessionManagerProj = Project(id = "sessionmanager", base = file("sessionManager"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ assemblySettings) settings(
        outputPath in assembly := new File(s"$outDir\\SessionManagerClient.jar"),
        jarName in assembly := "SessionManagerClient.jar",
        test in assembly := {}
    ) dependsOn(utilsProj)

lazy val lobbyProj = Project(id = "lobby", base = file("Lobby"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ assemblySettings) settings(
        outputPath in assembly := new File(s"$outDir\\Lobby.jar"),
        jarName in assembly := "Lobby.jar",
        test in assembly := {}
  ) dependsOn(utilsProj)
```

}

For some reason some of the projects end up with a deep nesting of 'project' folders. For example Utils might look like: 'Util/project/project/project/project/...

I'm using Intellij's SBT plugin to sync the presentation but managing the project with SBT. I'm not certain whether this is an SBT issue or an Intellij one.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Kurt

Comment: also asked at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sbt-dev/CRemIlAK4FY/X58xRb4murMJ. as a matter of online etiquette, if you're going to ask the same question at more than one place on the Internet, you should really cross-link, so somebody doesn't waste time answering in one place, when you already got the answer in the other place.

Comment: sorry. After I posted I realized that the topic may not belong on the forum so I posted this question, intending to remove my forum post.

Answer (score 0):

This is an IntelliJ issue (among many others related to the SBT plugin...)

I think you may have refreshed your config somewhere before defining a module and adding that module to the root project aggregates, which has a tendency to make a mess in IntelliJ.

This can be fixed in IntelliJ:

- detach your project from IntelliJ
- restart IntelliJ
- reimport your project